# Error while trying to integrate karate with wiremock

Tags: karate, wiremock

i am trying to integrate karate with wiremock and unable to find the @extendwith annotation for karate.
Could someone please help with this.

I have written the script for wiremock but it is failing at the starting the server. So I am trying to find the correct annotation for @extendwith.

Comment: just so you know, Karate includes an API mocking solution, so it is a replacement for wiremock: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty - sorry I can't help you with the annotation you are referring to, I don't know anything about it

Comment: Thank You Peter. Decided to go with karate mock.